# How to add just one entity in OneToMany relation in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

There are two tables one of them is Customer and another is Product, As you know Customer has OneToMany relation to Product and it shows below

In Customer Entity,

```
private Set<Product> products;
```

As you see, I use `Set` to implement OneToMany relation, but when I want to add just one entity as Product in the future, I have to fetch all of them products and do something like this,

```
Set<Product> products = customer.getProduct();
products.add(new Product(id, name, price));
dao.update(customer);
```

I think this is really heavy in process to fetch all of the Product from database just for add a  new entity, are there any other way in hibernate to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use bi-directional mapping so that Product has a Customer property, you could save the Product in isolation

```
private Customer Customer;

dao.Save(new Product(Customer, id, name, price));
```

That's obviously breaking your aggregate root...

Answer (score 0):

Use a List or a Bag instead. From the [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-collections-mostefficentinverse):

> we can add elements to a bag or list without needing to initialize
>   (fetch) the bag elements.